# how to use where condition in mongodb

Tags: sql, mongodb

I have a collection of mongodb, which contains "MoviesID, UserID, Rating", so this is to describe the how the users rate different movies, and a user can rate different movies, and certainly a movie can be rated by different users. Now I want to find all the users who rate similar movies with target user(For example : user 5).  Rating similar movies means that they rate at least same movie, or more. So how should I find all the users who rate similar movie with user 5? I just start learning mongodb.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a collection like this:

```
{
   movie: 1,
   user: 1,
   rating: 5
}, {
   movie: 2,
   user: 5,
   rating: 5
}, {
   movie: 3,
   user: 5,
   rating: 3
}
```

What you can do here is to find all the **movies** that is rated by user 5, like this:

```
db.collection.distinct("movie", { user: 5 }, function(err, movies) {
    // Will return array of distinct values for movies, where user is equal to 5.
    // From our collection above, this query will return [ 2, 3 ].

})
```

then:

```
db.collection.find({ movie: { $in: movies } }, function(err, result) {
    // Then we'll find the documents where movie is in the movies which
    // returned on our first query.
    // This will return [{ user: 5, ... }, { user: 1, ... }]
})
```

I can only think of doing this in two queries. I'm still thinking if this can be done by using **aggregate**.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I think this may work. However, how would I drop user:5 in the results? I mean, it is not similar to itself.

Comment: and what if I want the user to be input? Do i have to use python to get input and then query?

Answer (score 0):

To query data from MongoDB collection, you need to use MongoDB's find() method.

The basic syntax of find() method is as follows −

```
>db.COLLECTION_NAME.find()
```